# Why an extra "/.\" in linux path?

Tags: java, linux

Windows Scenario :-
I have a small piece of code which gets me the location of a specific folder in the directory.  The code is as given below:

```
browserPath = this.EnginePath + "\\Chrome_Selenium\\" + "chromedriver.exe";
```

This gets me the exact path : D:\Engine\Test

I am trying to use the same logic to get the path in linux machine.
The path where the Engine and Chrome Driver is stored in my linux machine (VM) is

/root/Engine/Chrome_Selenium

Now the linux part :-
I am using the following piece of code to get that

```
browserPath = this.EnginePath + "/Chrome_Selenium/" + "chromedriver";
```

The path this piece of code fetches is

/root/Engine/.\Chrome_Selenium\chromedriver

Can you please help me understand why the "/.\" is appearing in the path?

Comment: I suggest you're not running the code you think you're running, but there is never any need to use backslashes in Java filenames. Just use `/` on all platforms.

Comment: As @EJP suggested use `/` as delimter, I always use `/` as delimiter for paths. It works fine across all of the platforms we have same deployments in Windows, Unix etc. :)

Comment: In addition to EJP's comment: `/./` within a path is just the same as `/` alone because `.` is the directory itself.  In most cases I'd say: Don't think about that `/./` too much.  It just arises when paths get concatenated and the hind part is starting with `./foo..` to make clear it is a relative path based on the currect working directory.  So your path just is `/root/Engine/./Chrome_Selenium/chromedriver` which is the same as `/root/Engine/Chrome_Selenium/chromedriver`.

Comment: I don't see how `bar + "/Chrome_Selenium/" + foo` could ever append `\Chrome_Selenium\ ` with backslashes. The code you pasted in your question is not the code that is being executed.

Answer (score -1):

I am guessing the reason why `./` is added is because in linux in order to execute a script in the present working directory you need to address it this way: `./script` instead of `script`. Somehow it is attached even in cases where it is not needed (execution in other folder)

As for the main part as Alfe mentioned it does not make any different at the first place.

Comment: So your answer consists essentially of 'somehow'?